# CodeIgniter join string with !== mysql query to operation is not working and giving error

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `user_phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `building_units` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 = Active(default), 0 = Inactive',
  `user_role` enum('0','1','2','3') NOT NULL DEFAULT '2' COMMENT '0=Manager,1=Admin,2=User,3=Tenant',
  `user_ip` int(39) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE `building_admins_tbl` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `building_id` int(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ',
  `building_admin_id` int(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'FK',
  `user_id` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_id` int(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I have written the following query:

```
$select = 'users.user_id,users.user_name,users.user_role,users.status,building_admins_tbl.building_admin_id';
$join_str = 'users.user_id != building_admins_tbl.building_admin_id';
$where = ['users.user_role'=>'1','users.status'=>'1'];

        $q =$this->db    
                    ->select($select)
                    ->where($where)
                    ->from('users')    
                    ->join('building_admins_tbl',$join_str)
                    ->get();
        $admin_list =$q->result_array();
```

In the above query the join string is important. I want to get only those rows `where(users.user_id != building_admins_tbl.building_admin_id)` with the where condition as well.

But I am not getting the expecting result. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you should be joining, because you haven't properly set up your foreign keys, and if you did you didn't include that information, but I'll give it a shot because the real answer is that you want to do the join, but use a different WHERE clause.

You must actually join the other table, and you can't use !=:

```
// This looks like you are trying to join on the admin ID, which is probably wrong
$join_str = 'users.user_id = building_admins_tbl.building_admin_id';

// If you are trying to get tenants, it's probably supposed to be:
$join_str = 'users.user_id = building_admins_tbl.tenant_id';

// If you are trying to join with the users table, it might be:
$join_str = 'users.user_id = building_admins_tbl.user_id';
```

But then make sure you aren't including admins

```
$where = [
    'users.user_role !=' => '1', // Do not include user role #1 (admins)
    'users.status'       => '1'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

after inserting just load your view page

and add these line in your view page

`$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` //within php tag

these will give you raw query in your view just copy the query and execute it in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
    $q = $this->db
            ->from('users')
            ->where(['user_role'=>'1'])
            ->where(['status'=>'1'])
            ->where("
              NOT EXISTS (
                select building_admin_id from building_admins_tbl where  users.user_id = building_admins_tbl.building_admin_id)") 
            ->get();
    $data['admins_list'] = $q->result_array();
```

Comment: The subquery should be prepared earlier using query builder methods, then that rendered string should be fed to the parent query's NOT EXISTS condition for query portability.